# Роль атрибута for в данном примере

Tags: html, вёрстка, form, input, label

В моей книге был приведён следующий пример:

```html
<form action="" method="post">

  <label for="username">Имя пользователя:<br />
        <input type="text" name="imyapolz" required="required"/>
        </label> <br />
  <label for="password">Пароль:<br />
        <input type="password" name="parol" required="required"/>
        </label><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

Не понимаю зачем здесь атрибут for. Ранее в книге был приведён пример с переключателями, где роль for была понятна: благодаря for, чтобы выбрать один из вариантов можно кликать не только на кружочек, но и на текст у кружочка. Пример из книги с переключателями:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Формы 13</title>
</head>

<body>
  Пол:
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="pol" value="male" />
  <label for="male">Мужской</label>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="pol" value="female" />
  <label for="female">Женский</label>
</body>

</html>
```

К тому же, в примере с переключателями понятно, что присваивается атрибуту for.

Ему присваивается id, который был указан в input.

А в первом примере с вводом имени пользователя и пароля непонятно что вообще присваивается for. Откуда взялось "username" и "password"? ]

Просто так в лишний раз писать любое значение в for, стоящее в input?  Для чего это вообще делать? Что от этого меняется?

Я постарался сформулировать вопрос как можно понятнее, но если что-то неясно готов уточнить :)

Comment: в первом пример атрибуты `for` не нужны. Они даже мешают, так как элементов с такими `id` нет, а `input`-ы и так находятся внутри `label`-ов

Comment: Уберите for и проверьте валидатором - будет ошибка. Это стандарт. Вопрос о его логике к разработчикам...

Comment: @Ljil всё с точностью до наоборот: если в первом примере не убрать for, то валидатор сыпет ошибками, а если убрать, то ошибок нет (кроме пустого action)

Comment: @JustLearn - если в книге написано `name="imyapolz"` - выбросите ее, пока не поздно. И наверно там должно быть написано username и тогда все было было стройно и логично.

Comment: @KoVadim всё равно не логично, потому что, во-первых, for должен указывать не на name, а во-вторых, input и так завёрнут в label

Comment: под "стройно и логично" я не подразумевал правильно. Может скажете имя книги?

Comment: @KoVadim по слову «imyapolz» какая-то книга неплохо гуглится

Comment: @andreymal, похоже переводчики постарались

Comment: @andreymal, но похоже даже в оригинале он не использует id в этом месте

Comment: а вот это уже печально.  Но в любом случае, автор любой книги может ошибаться. И всегда следует использовать поисковые системы и документацию

Comment: @Ljil убрал for ошибки никакой не возникает. Всё верно работает. если оставить поле пустым и нажать отправить, то появляется окошко заполните это поле.

Comment: Т.е. нет необходимости писать for в label?

Answer (score 0):

День добрый. Подскажите книгу, в которой нашли этот пример. Возможно, он приведен как неверный. Можно начать с того, что дописав немного кода и проверив вашу форму, окажется что она не проходит тест на валидность от w3c.
Полный пример тут: https://jsfiddle.net/i_pix_by/7zeLqx0a/2/

```
<body>
    <form action="send.php" method="post">
        <label for="username">Имя пользователя:<br />
            <input type="text" name="imyapolz" required="required" />
        </label> <br />
        <label for="password">Пароль:<br />
            <input type="password" name="parol" required="required" />
        </label><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Проверить на валидность можно здесь: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Однако!
Допустимо вкладывать инпуты в лэйблы:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
    <label for="text1">
        text1
        <input type="text" value="text1" id="text1">
    </label>
    <br>
    <label for="text2">
        text2
        <input type="text" value="text2" id="text2">
    </label>
</form>
```

Данный пример пройдет валидацию.

К слову...

```
<input type="text" name="imyapolz" required="required"/>
<input type="password" name="parol" required="required"/>
```

name="imyapolz" и name="parol"
Транслитерация: написание русских слов английскими буквами допустима, но это считается очень плохой практикой.

Comment: По слову «imyapolz» книга собственно неплохо гуглится

Comment: Книга: Джон Дакетт HTML и CSS Разработка и создание веб-сайтов

Comment: Кстати меня насмешило то, что у меня в книге зачастую русские слова пишут английскими буквами) Я так понял, что книга рассчитана на людей, которые вообще не знают английский, т.к. очень часто какие-нибудь названия тегов помечаются звёздочкой и внизу страницы указывается их перевод))